# Error ITMS-90032 Invalid Image Path - No Image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon29x29

Tags: ios, xcode, upload

I have a problem at uploading my app to iTunes connect. I get this error:

[image: ERROR-ITMS-90032]

I put the AppIcons in the Assets.xcassets folder, they are working properly on the devices.

When i look into my Info.plist file, there is no key "CFBundleIcons"...

Could the Contents.json be a problem?? Mine looks just like this:

[image: contentsdotjson file]

Thanks in advance for your help!